# copy IFile contents to another IFile

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

So I have the following:

```
IFile oldIvy = this.project.getFile("ivy.xml");

IFile newIvy = this.project.getFile("tempIvy.xml);
```

I have made changes to the `tempIvy.xml` and now I want to copy the contents of `tempIvy.xml` back over to `ivy.xml`.

I have tried methods such as copy, setContents, etc. It just doesn't seem to be copying the contents of one to the other.

Any suggestions?

e.g. I've done:

```
oldIvy.setContents(newIvy.getContents(), true, false, monitor);
```

Here is the [API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIFile.html) I have been referring to..

Thanks!

Comment: Is the code throwing any exceptions?

Comment: After some more investigation, I am getting a resources out of sync error on the tempIvy.xml. Trying to figure out how to fix the syncing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make changes to a workspace file from outside of the workspace or by using non-Eclipse APIs such as the normal Java file I/O operations then you will need to use `IFile.refreshLocal` to tell Eclipse to pick up the changes.

`refreshLocal` is not needed if you use the Eclipse APIs to change the file contents.

There is an option to do the refresh automatically in Preferences > General > Workspace but your code should not rely on this being set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using refreshLocal() as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_should_I_use_refreshLocal%3F).  That should force Eclipse to refresh its references to the file and then you should be able to access the contents.

Comment: this.project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, monitor);              fixed the issue. Just a refresh on the IFile(s) was not working correctly.